# Как преобразовать метод Math.Pow в decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, математика, дизассемблирование

Возникла проблема: необходимо извлечь 128-битный корень n-ной степени, но точности double для этого не хватает! Для меня остаётся загадкой работа метода Math.Pow, так как он умудряется в считанные миллисекунды извлекать корень огромной степени. Когда я вскрывал данный метод через .NET Reflector, то ничего там не обнаружил - метод не поддаётся рефлексии!
Итак, мне нужен тот же метод, только работающий с типом decimal. Как это реализовать?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6425501/2881286

Comment: Decimal вам не поможет, нужно искать библиотеку с типом BigDecimal. `Math.Pow` работает через логарифмы и ряды Тейлора: `x^y = e^(y ln x)`. Он одинаково быстро считает что квадратный корень, что корень миллионной степени.

Comment: а чего не хватает? вам нужно много знаков после запятой?? 2^(1/128) ~ 1.00543.., 5^(1/128) ~ 0.01256.. - в чем проблема?? чем выше степень корня тем ближе к 1

Answer (score 0):

[Известна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F_n-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) итерационная формула

[image: Итерационная формула]

Начальное значение x<sub>0</sub> = 1.

Answer (score 0):

подсказка: 
 `sqrt(n,x128ab) = sqrt(n, x64a*Max_64 + x64b), если x64a*Max <<x64b` там есть некая формула приближения, а

> Для меня остаётся загадкой работа метода Math.Pow, так как он
>   умудряеся в считанные миллисекунды извлекать корень огромной степени.

делается лукап- таблицей и волшебными числами